# Javascript: how to add an element to an object if it not exist

Tags: javascript

Javascript: how to add an element to an object if it not exist

I would like to populate the object as I did with the array
(if is not present add to it)

```js
// push : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

let items = ['aa','xx'];

function newList(item) {

 if (items.indexOf(item) === -1) {
  items.push(item);
 }
 return console.log(items)

}

newList('aa');
newList('bb');
newList('aa');

// how i can do the same with this object?

let itemsObj =
[
 {id: 'Id AA', name: 'Name AA'},
 {id: 'Id BB', name: 'Name BB'},
 {id: 'Id CC', name: 'Name CC'},
 {id: 'Id DD', name: 'Name DD'},
 {id: 'Id EE', name: 'Name EE'},

];

let newItemA = {id: 'Id XX', name: 'Name XX'};
let newItemB = {id: 'Id AA', name: 'Name AA'};

// TODO
```

Comment: Are you trying to add to an existing object if the key is not already present? For example, adding `name` if not defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Array.reduce" and "Array.from" to achieve this with the help of "Sets"

```js
let itemsObj =
[
 {id: 'Id AA', name: 'Name AA'},
 {id: 'Id BB', name: 'Name BB'},
 {id: 'Id CC', name: 'Name CC'},
 {id: 'Id DD', name: 'Name DD'},
 {id: 'Id EE', name: 'Name EE'},

];

let newItemA = {id: 'Id XX', name: 'Name XX'};
let newItemB = {id: 'Id AA', name: 'Name AA'};


function addItem(item) {
  return Array.from(
            (itemsObj.concat(item)).reduce((s, d) => s.add(JSON.stringify(d)) , new Set)
            , (d) => JSON.parse(d))
}

console.log(addItem(newItemA))

console.log(addItem(newItemB))
```

Comment: your solution works fine thanks

Comment: Great your issue is resolved!!